# Recibo mail pero no se confirma

Tags: php, email

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<form action="assets/php/sendmail.php" method="post" id="contactForm">
<p class="text_cont"><input id="name" input type="text" name="name" placeholder="<?php echo FORM_PLACEHOLDER_1 ?>" required></p>
<p class="text_cont"><input id="email" input type="text" name="email" placeholder="<?php echo FORM_PLACEHOLDER_2 ?>" required></p>
<p class="text_cont"><input id="subject" input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="<?php echo FORM_PLACEHOLDER_3 ?>"></p>
<p class="text_cont"><textarea id="message" textarea name="message" placeholder="<?php echo FORM_PLACEHOLDER_4 ?>"></textarea></p>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-3 col-sm-3"><p><input type="submit" id="send" class="btn btn-default" value="<?php echo SEND_PLACEHOLDER ?>" /></p></div>
```

**sendmail.php** contiene el siguiente código porqué la compañía hosting me lo dio para que funcione el formulario (servidores windows). Lo he modificado un poco:

```
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~( E_NOTICE | E_STRICT | E_DEPRECATED ) );
require_once "Mail.php";
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subject']);
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
$to = 'my@mail.com';
$from = $email;
$host = 'smtp.myhost.com';
$username = 'usernameformail';
$password = 'passwordformail';
$body =
utf8_decode("This mail has been written from your web: \r\n") .
utf8_decode("Name: " . $name . "\r\n") .
utf8_decode("Email: " . $email . "\r\n") .
utf8_decode("Subject: " . $subject . "\r\n") .
utf8_decode("Message: " . $message);
$headers = array (
'From' => $from,
'To' => $to,
'Subject' => $subject,
);
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('host' => $host,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
};
$name = '';
$email = '';
$subject = '';
$message = '';
?>
```

El caso es que cuando el usuario escribe y envía el mail, todo llega correcto. El problema es en la condición *"if (PEAR::isError($mail))"*. Cuando se clica el botón "enviar" la web no redirecciona:

```
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
header('Location: http://www.myweb.com/error.php');
} else {
header('Location: http://www.myweb.com/thanks.php');
};
```

Si escribo un script tampoco:

```
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> redirect in javascript to error </script>";
} else {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> redirect in javascript to thanks</script>";
};
```

El mail siempre llega correctamente pero el usuario nunca sabe si todo funciona correctamente. ¿Pueden indicarme dónde puede estar mi error?

Comment: ¿Qué ves si haces `print_r($mail)` después de `$mail = $smtp->send(...);`?

Comment: ¿Con los echo tampoco funciona, no muestra el mensaje?: `if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "*******</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
};
` le puse `****` por si acaso muestra una cadena vacía.

Comment: También, es posible que necesites activar el modo `debug` en el mail factory, algo así: `$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
array ('debug'=>true, 'host' => $host,
'auth' => true,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password));`

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, parece ser que en el botón "submit" debo aplicarle una orden javascript para que me redireccione expresamente a sendmail.php. Parece ser que cuando me direcciona al fichero en qúestión, siempre me ejecuta la orden "if (PEAR::isError($mail))" pero no pasa del "else", por lo tanto, me redirecciona a un sólo sitio, ignorando el "else". Da igual que redireccione o ponga el consejo dado, nunca me hace la sentencia "else". @A. Cedano. Muchas gracias.

Comment: por lo tanto, nunca me redirecciona a thanks.php. Muchas gracias también a @fedorqui, aunque no entiendo muy bien dónde debería detecetar el error en el texto que me aparece.

Comment: Creo que estás confundido sobre la forma en que funcionan los form. No tienes que darle ninguna orden al botón submit para que te redireccione a ninguna parte. Cuando aprietas el botón submit de un form se ejecuta lo que tengas indicado en el action del mismo. Yo lo haría usando jQuery/Ajax, que permite ejecutar en background las acciones de envío e imprimir en un div de la misma página donde se encuentra el formulario un mensaje con el resultado  sin cambiar de página. Saludos.

Comment: @A. Cedano, empecé haciendolo como indicas y al apretar el botón no pasaba nada (enviaba el mail, pero no sabía si había errores o no), por lo que hice un redireccionamiento expreso con javascript para comprobar los "echo" de sendmail.php. Voy a hacer unas cuantas pruebas más, creando un div que me dé resultados en la misma página del formulario. Responderé tan pronto tenga resultados. De momento, sigue dándome que hay errores (no sé quales) pero el mail se envía. Gracias.

Comment: Yo lo haría usando jQuery . Si tienes algún problema puedes plantearlo aquí y seguro que encontrarás ayuda .

Comment: Al final conseguí encontrar respuesta y todo funciona correctamente. Encontré el siguiente link que me ayudó a estructurar Ajax, muchas gracias a todos por aportar vuestro grano de arena y permitirme ir tirando del hilo para encontrar información al respecto. Este es el link (no sé si está permitido revelar fuentes por si se duda de que hago spam, en ese caso, algún moderador me lo edite: http://web.tursos.com/como-hacer-un-formulario-de-contacto-ajax-con-php-y-jquery/)